# Обмен сообщениями между объектами

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Имеется проблема в проектированием системы классов.

Есть абстрактный класс «Участник», который умеет посылать информацию в виде абстрактного класса «Запрос» другим «Участникам».
Также имеется иерархия наследников от «Участник» и иерархия наследников «Запроса» каждый со своим поведением.
 Проблема в том, что обмен запросами реализован на уровне базового класса «Участник», который знает только о методах и свойствах  базового класса «Запрос». Следовательно, реализуя наследников от «Участник», и желая получить доступ к дополнительным полям наследников «Запроса», придется заниматься приведением типов, что говорит об ущербности модели.

Как бы это организовать пологичнее?

Comment: observer, не?

Comment: А почему не хотите реализовать паттерн издатель-подписчик?

Comment: Во первых все "Участники" сами выбирают конкретного получателя "Запроса", а во вторых "Запрос" должен быть расширяемым. Т.е. я могу создать "Участника" с уникальной моделью поведения и определить новый тип "Запроса" с дополнительными свойствами, который должны уметь обрабатывать новые виды "Участников". Что-о я не понимаю как тут может помочь модель наблюдателя.

Comment: Отличный вопрос. 

Замечательно высвечивает кучу проблем, которые возникают у разработчика при желании строго соблюдать каноны ООП.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наличие поведения у запроса - это странно. Очевидно, что ваша иерархия не имеет смысла, т.к. классы наследники имеют интерфейсы, которые несовместимы с интерфейсом базового класса. Т.е. принцип подстановки не соблюдается в полной мере. Может быть имеет смысл у запросов оставить признак (свойство этого класса или его тип), определяющий тип запроса, а поведение вынести в отдельные классы, которые знают, что делать с конкретным типом запроса (назовем их обработчиками). У обработчиков будет одинаковый интерфейс (метод handle), но разное поведение. Участникам остается передевать запросы правильным обработчикам в соответствии с их типом.

И не заигрывайтесь с наследованием. Чаще всего это неправильное отношение.

Comment: У запроса нет поведения. У наследников запроса лишь появляются дополнительные свойства (т.е. передается дополнительная информация). Сейчас получателю приходится проверять экземпляром какого класса, является поступивший запрос и потом делать приведение типа, чтобы получить доступ к дополнительным свойствам. Это конечно не смертельно, но как то далеко от ООП.

Comment: @nrw в такой постановке вы не решите задачу без приведения типов. Еще раз скажу, что наследование здесь только мешает. Попробуйте представить специфические свойства запросов в более общей форме. Например в HTTP-запросе есть параметры, заголовки и тело, и все обработчики будут работать с этими свойствами, но каждый по своему для разных запросов.

Comment: Заранее набивать класс запроса полями для резерва на будущее, это уж очень грязный код. И в любом случае в будущем может появиться ситуация, когда этих полей не хватит. А с приведением типов система остается расширяемой и не требует переделки базовых классов, так что предпочту все же последнее.

Comment: @nrw, у вас есть продуманная схема того, как это будет выглядеть в финале? Я не могу просто придумать расширяющийся запрос, хоть убей. В крайнем случае можно просто прицепить метод `getExtraData()` и тянуть его когда надо.

Comment: Хотя конечно еще можно сделать у класса запроса свойство в виде динамического массива именованных свойств. Тогда никакого приведения типов не надо, но по моему это еще извращеннее :)

Comment: Fike, сейчас например имеется базовый класс запроса, который хранит информацию исключительно об отправителе и получателе (запросы пересылаются через объект-диспетчер). Далее идет расширение на "Запрос на перемещение", который содержит координаты. "Запрос на совместную операцию с отправителем", который содержит некие данные и т.п.

Comment: Сделайте отдельный обработчик для каждого запроса, как советовал a_gura. Обработчик получайте через фабрику. В обработчик передайте отправителя, получателя и собственно сам запрос.